# Slow startup time of Windows 10 using Intel SSD 750 Series

Tags: windows-10, boot

My startup time from pressing the power button to the first sight of Windows 10 desktop is 45 seconds to 55 seconds which is bad for my high end gaming rig.

It's been a month since I've build my PC and I really want to fix this slow startup problem.

This is my rig:
Full list: https://ca.pcpartpicker.com/user/soscookies/saved/#view=MDm6Mp

- Intel Core I7-5820K 3.60GHZ
- Asus X99-DELUXE II ATX LGA2011-3 Motherboard (Don't buy that)
- 8x Kingston HyperX Fury Black 16GB (4 x 4GB) DDR4-2133 Memory
- Intel 750 Series 400GB PCI-E Solid State Drive
- MSI GeForce GTX 980 Ti 6GB Video Card

All windows update are done

I have not noticed anything bad during my month of utilization.

I expected under 20 seconds, it's compared with other 3000$ computers and what I've seen on the Internet.

I've disable most of the startup apps, using the startup tab on the task manager but it doesn't give much improvement on the startup time.

So for exemple, I shut down my PC with the windows menu and I wait until its completely off.

1. 0:00 I push to start the power button and the stopwatch
2. 0:26 I can    now see the Asus logo,  (It's a black screen before)
3. 0:34 I can now    see the windows 10 logo
4. 0:49 I can now see the desktop

I have 145GB/372GB, Windows 10, some games and program are installed. I use the antivirus that comes with windows 10, Windows defender.
I reboot 2-3 times a day, but these days for testing purposes I boot quite often.
Once it's started it's fast.

I've done some Test for the Intel 750 Series 400GB PCI-E Solid State Drive, everything is fine.
[image]

Here is an image of the boot order choice.

[image]

Comment: *"45 seconds to 55 seconds which is bad"* Compared to what? What's your frame of reference? What's your target boot time (i.e., how long would you feel is an "acceptable" time from power-on to desktop)? Frankly, 45 seconds from power-on to usable system sounds quite good to me. (For perspective: How many times per day do you reboot the computer?)

Comment: Search "See which process start up automatically when you start Windows" using the search feature on Windows 10.  Select the Startup tab if it isn't already, and disable some of the applications.  This may help.

Comment: Is this from cold-boot (restart) or from a shutdown/hibernate (fastboot)? What do you have installed? What antivirus? What programs boot at startup? How often do you need to reboot? Is the computer slow in any other way? Are there any other symptoms of "slowness"?

Comment: MBR or GPT; 45 seconds MBR that is fast; GPT that is extremely slow.

Comment: I've answered by editing the post

Comment: How's your power supply?

Comment: How's your power supply? It's a EVGA 750W 80+ Gold Certified Fully-Modular ATX Power Supply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: X99 motherboard has also slow startup, its possible to get a small improvement with dram timing settings

Final time: 00:39 to 00:45

The longer boot time is due to longer initialization time on PCIe* devices
(The Intel 750 SSD is a PCI device)

Found there:
http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/solid-state-drives/consumer-ssds/000016211.html

> Why does the Intel® SSD 750 Series take longer to boot compared to
>   SATA drives?
>
> The longer boot time is due to longer initialization time on PCIe*
>   devices, and in part because of the data center nature of the drive.

Drivers can be updated, improvement of 5 to 10 seconds, 
Details there https://communities.intel.com/thread/75802

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that most of the time is spent waiting for the BIOS to finish booting - Try booting to the BIOS and checking hard drive boot order, if its doing a full memory check before booting.

Comment: I've look at the setting in the bios again, I've changed the boot order to only the ssd and there is no improvement. The motherboard shows a number on a 2 number lcd. It doesn't stop on a particular number. How can I check if it's doing a memory check, I've looked thoroughly the bios menu...?

Answer (score 0):

The wait is for the PCI-e bus to initialize.  You would have to take action to speed this up (bios update, bios settings change, etc).

Comment: I've tried many things so far. Different bios updates and settings. I'm still at 45 seconds. By the way dont buy asus deluxe II motherboard, many problems...